# Suricata: Error opening file threshold.config

Tags: windows-server-2012, snort, ids

I use [Suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/) 4.0.5 (an open source IDPS) on windows server 2012. It raises the below error when I run it, however, it runs.

```
Error opening file threshold.config
```

I searched for this error and find these links:

[Suricata can't start due to missing file](https://github.com/StamusNetworks/Amsterdam/issues/7)
[Suricata error: error opening file threshold.config](https://success.alienvault.com/s/question/0D50Z00008oGtKPSA0/suricata-error-error-opening-file-etcsuricatathresholdconfig)

According to these links I understand I have to create an empty `threshold.config` manually.

**Question:**
What is the `threshold.config` file?
Why should I create it manually?